# (Unity) Can I Add Event when Particle is emitted?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

My Particle Emit effects when object was moved
so I wanna Play Sound *(e.walk sound)*  when Particle is emitted
How Can I Do that?

Desired Code

```
ParticleSystem particle;

private void Awake()
{
    particle.onEmit += () => SoundManager.Instance.PlaySFX();
}
```

Comment: well if its triggered by a move, why not have the move trigger the sound too?